# Google Maps API v3 (one infowindow open at a time)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

Does someone know how to modify this code so that google maps closes infowindows when you open another?

In other words, I want only one infowindow open at all times. I looked around on stackoverflow but couldn't seem to implement people's solutions in this code.

```
function initMapsDealers(){

objectLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(25.64152637306577, 1.40625);

var myOptions = {
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom: 2,
    center: objectLocation,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas-dealers"), myOptions);
var image1 = '/gfx/iconPloegerGreen.png';
var image2 = '/gfx/iconPloegerGreen.png';
var image3 = '/gfx/iconPloegerDealer.png';

/* Info windows */
<?

function replace_newline($string) {
  return (string)str_replace(array("\r", "\r\n", "\n"), '', $string);
}


$i = 0;
foreach($dealers as $dealer)
{
    $dealerLanden[$dealer['Land']][] = $dealer;

    if($dealer['lat'] != "" && $dealer['lon'] != "")
    {
        $i++;

        ?>
        objectLocation<?= $i; ?> = new google.maps.LatLng(<?= $dealer['lat']; ?>, <?= $dealer['lon']; ?>);

        var contentString<?= $i; ?> =
            '<div class="infoWindow">'+
            '<strong><?= str_replace("'","", $dealer['name']); ?></strong><br>'+
            '<?= replace_newline($dealer['content']); ?>'+
            '</div>';

        var infowindow<?= $i; ?> = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString<?= $i; ?>
        }); 

        var marker<?= $i; ?> = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: objectLocation<?= $i; ?>,
            title:"<?= $dealer['name']; ?>",
            map: map,
            icon: <?

            if($dealer['group'] == "Hoofdkantoor"){ ?>image1<? }
            elseif($dealer['group'] == "Oxbo"){ ?>image2<? }
            elseif($dealer['group'] == "Dealers"){ ?>image3<? } 
            else{ ?>image1<? }?>

        }); 

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker<?= $i; ?>, 'click', function() {
            infowindow<?= $i; ?>.open(map,marker<?= $i; ?>);
        });
        <?
    }
}

?>                      

resizeSection();

};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API - opening a single infoWindow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796318/google-maps-api-opening-a-single-infowindow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a google recommendation what to do if you only want one InfoWindow [API documentaion for InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows).

It is:

> InfoWindows may be attached to either Marker objects (in which case
>   their position is based on the marker's location) or on the map itself
>   at a specified LatLng. If you only want one info window to display at
>   a time (as is the behavior on Google Maps), you need only create one
>   info window, which you can reassign to different locations or markers
>   upon map events (such as user clicks). Unlike behavior in V2 of the
>   Google Maps API, however, a map may now display multiple InfoWindow
>   objects if you so choose.
>
> To change the info window's location you may either change its
>   position explicitly by calling setPosition() on the info window, or by
>   attaching it to a new marker using the InfoWindow.open() method. Note
>   that if you call open() without passing a marker, the InfoWindow will
>   use the position specified upon construction through the InfoWindow
>   options object.

So try to follow these suggenstions.

Comment: The correct link for InfoWindow documentation is https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution to have only one infowindow open at one time:

```
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: infocontent,
    maxWidth: 200
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

    if($('.gm-style-iw').length) {
         $('.gm-style-iw').parent().hide();
    }
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    
});
```

Comment: The remove() function can cause a null exception. I think that it would be better to use $(".gm-style-iw").parent("div").hide();