# Show only one infobubble "at a time" in google maps API 3

Tags: google-maps, infobubble

I am trying to make it so that only one infobubble shows at a time, in other words to toggle infobubble. The marker gets assigned this event handler in a for loop, looping through the marker array.

at the moment this works in a way that opens the infobubble but never closes it. I can click multiple markers and each will have the infobubble with out closing the previous one

Iv tried adding `infobuble2.close();` but the closes iv got with it is i would have to click on the markers twice to close the previous infobubbles.

Iv also tried testing if the infobubble is open using `infoBubble2.isOpen()` it appears to only be false.

And yes if your  wondering i have tried infowindow, and the functionality works well using it, but because of design constrains i need to style the popup accordingly 
below is my code

```
  var infoBubble2;

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

             infoBubble2 = new InfoBubble({
                map: map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(-35, 151),
                shadowStyle: 1,
                padding: 0,
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                borderRadius: 4,
                arrowSize: 10,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#2c2c2c',
                disableAutoPan: true,
                hideCloseButton: !0,
                arrowPosition: 30,
                backgroundClassName: 'phoney',
                arrowStyle: 2
              });

            infoBubble2.setContent("some content");
            infoBubble2.open(map, marker);
  });
```

Comment: What is Google Maps API v3.1?  If that is supposed to be the "first release" of the Google Maps Javascript API v3, it was retired a long time ago, see [versioning](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning)

Comment: Im using this https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API v3 (one infowindow open at a time)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111555/google-maps-api-v3-one-infowindow-open-at-a-time)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map V3 - Allow only one infobox to be displayed at a time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908132/google-map-v3-allow-only-one-infobox-to-be-displayed-at-a-time/10908459#10908459)

Comment: possible dubs yes, but infobox may be similar to infobubble, they are  still different scripts. with possibly diffrent option and methods hence why i posted the question. At the end of the day just adjusting the logic solved the issuse for me. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by declaring the infobubble2 variable outside the initialize() function and then assigning it the value of new infobubble(); within the initialize(), then the onclick event which is assigner to each marker opens and populates the content of the infobubble.

Below is what i did. Thanks for the help everyone.

```
var infoBubble2;

function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
          zoom: zoom,
          minZoom: 0, maxZoom: 20,
          center: myLatLng,
          mapTypeId: maptype,
          mapTypeControl:false,
          streetViewControl:false,
          panControl:false
      };
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

   infoBubble2 = new InfoBubble({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-35, 151),
            shadowStyle: 1,
            padding: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)',
            borderRadius: 4,
            arrowSize: 10,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#2c2c2c',
            disableAutoPan: true,
            hideCloseButton: !0,
            arrowPosition: 30,
            backgroundClassName: 'phoney',
            arrowStyle: 2
          });

      $.getJSON('include/jsonCatPoints.php', function(data) {
          for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
            placeMarker(data[i]['cat_lat'], data[i]['cat_long'], map);
          }
        });


}//ends initialize

function placeMarker(lat, longg, map) {
      var image = 'img/cat_marker.png';
         marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,longg),
          map: map,
          icon: image
        });
      makeBubble(map, "test" +lat, marker);
       markers.push(marker);
  }//ends placeMarker


function makeBubble(map, contentString, marker) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoBubble2.setContent("message"+contentString);
        infoBubble2.open(map, marker)
 });
}// ends makeBubble
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
function f_createBalloon(num, marker) {
    balloons[num] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: ballonInfo[num]
    });
    balloonListeners[num] = new google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',
        function () {
            f_closeBalloons();
            balloons[num].open(map, marker);
        });
}

function f_closeBalloons() {
    for (var j in balloons) {
        if (balloons[j]) balloons[j].close(map, markers[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want one to show up at a time, then only create one object and re-use it, rather than continually creating new objects and trying to manage them, like this:

```
 var infoBubble2 = new InfoBubble({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-35, 151),
    shadowStyle: 1,
    padding: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)',
    borderRadius: 4,
    arrowSize: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#2c2c2c',
    disableAutoPan: true,
    hideCloseButton: !0,
    arrowPosition: 30,
    backgroundClassName: 'phoney',
    arrowStyle: 2
  });


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
    infoBubble2.close();
    infoBubble2.setContent("some content");
    infoBubble2.open(map, marker);
  });
```