# Google Maps API - (Using OverlayView) Only have one map marker open at a time?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I am trying to figure out with OverlayView for Google Maps API how to make it to where if you have one map marker opened already, and you try to open another, it automatically closes the open one, so there is really only one marker open at a time, and so on. Here is the js code I currently have already:

```
var GMap = (function() {
  var that = {};
  that.map = null;
  that.center = new google.maps.LatLng(33.7856030000,-84.4090570000);
  that.map_type = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;
  that.markers = {};
  that.windows = {};
  that.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  that.use_bounds = false;
  that.watch_click = false;
  that.zoom = 10;
  that.addCityMarker = function(opts) {
    that.markers[opts.id] = that.standardMarker(opts);
    var myLatlng = that.markers[opts.id].getPosition();
    google.maps.event.addListener(that.markers[opts.id], "click", function(e) {
      that.windows[opts.id] = new InfoBox({
        data: opts,
        latlng: myLatlng,
        map: that.map,
        type: 'city'
      });
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(that.markers[opts.id], "click");
    if(that.use_bounds == true) {
      that.bounds.extend(myLatlng);
    }
  };
  that.addCityMarkers = function(data) {
    for(var i in data) {
      if(data[i]) {
        that.addCityMarker(data[i]);
      }
    }
  };
  that.addCommunityMarker = function(opts) {
    if(!that.markers[opts.data.id]) {
      that.markers[opts.data.id] = that.standardMarker(opts);
      var myLatlng = that.markers[opts.data.id].getPosition();
      google.maps.event.addListener(that.markers[opts.data.id], "click", function(e) {
        that.windows[opts.data.id] = new InfoBox({
          data: opts.data,
          latlng: myLatlng,
          map: that.map,
          type: 'community'
        });
      });
      google.maps.event.trigger(that.markers[opts.data.id], "click");
      if(that.use_bounds == true) {
        that.bounds.extend(myLatlng);
      }
    } else {
      console.log('skipped adding duplicate community window to map');
    }
  };
  that.addCommunityMarkers = function(data) {
    for(var i in data) {
      if(data[i]) {
        GMap.addCommunityMarker(data[i]);
      }
    }
  };
  that.finish = function() {
    if(that.use_bounds == true) {
     that.map.fitBounds(that.bounds); 
    }
  };
  that.standardMarker = function(opts) {
    var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
      '/images/map/trans.png',
      new google.maps.Size(1,1),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0)
    );
    var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
      '/images/map/trans.png',
      new google.maps.Size(1,1),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0)
    );
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      icon: icon,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(opts.lat,opts.lng),
      map: that.map,
      shadow: shadow
    });
    return marker;
  }
  that.triggerMarker = function(id) {
    if(that.windows[id]) {
      that.map.setCenter(that.markers[id].getPosition());
      if(!$('#info_window_'+id).hasClass('open')) {
        $('#info_window_'+id+' a.expand').trigger('click'); 
      }
    } else {
      console.log('no marker for: '+id);
    }
  };
  that.resize = function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(that.map, 'resize');
    if(that.use_bounds == true) {
      that.map.fitBounds(that.bounds);
    } else {
      that.map.setCenter(that.center); 
    }
  };
  that.initialize = function() {
      var latlng = that.center;
    var myOptions = {
      center: latlng,
      navigationControl: true,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      navigationControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.LARGE
      },
      mapTypeId: that.map_type,
      panControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
      },
      scrollwheel: false,
      zoom: that.zoom,
      zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
      }
    };
    that.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  };
  return that;
})();

function InfoBox(opts) {
  google.maps.OverlayView.call(this);
  this.data_ = opts.data;
  this.type_ = opts.type;
  this.latlng_ = opts.latlng;
  this.map_ = opts.map;
  var me = this;
  this.setMap(this.map_);
}

InfoBox.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

InfoBox.prototype.draw = function() {
  // Creates the element if it doesn't exist already.
  if(this.type_ == 'community') {
    this.createElement();
    if (!this.div_) return;

    var pixPosition = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng_);
    if (!pixPosition) return;

    // Now position our DIV based on the DIV coordinates of our bounds
    if(this.div_.hasClass('open')) {
      this.div_.css('left', (pixPosition.x + -36) + "px");
      this.div_.css('top', (pixPosition.y + -158) + "px");
    } else {
      this.div_.css('left', (pixPosition.x + -36) + "px");
      this.div_.css('top', (pixPosition.y + -85) + "px");
    }
    this.div_.css('display', 'block'); 
  } else if(this.type_ == 'city') {
    this.createCityElement();
    if (!this.div_) return;

    var pixPosition = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng_);
    if (!pixPosition) return;

    // Now position our DIV based on the DIV coordinates of our bounds
    this.div_.css('left', (pixPosition.x + -38) + "px");
    this.div_.css('top', (pixPosition.y + -38) + "px");
    this.div_.css('display', 'block'); 
  }
};

InfoBox.prototype.createElement = function() {
  var me = this;
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  var div = this.div_;
  var data = this.data_;
  if (!div) {
    div = this.div_ = $('<div class="map_info_window" id="info_window_'+data.id+'">'
      +'<a href="#" class="expand">Expand</a>'
      +'<div class="info_window_content">'
        +'<div class="thumb"><img src="'+data.image+'" title="'+data.title+'" /></div>'
        +'<div class="info_window_data">'
          +'<p class="title">'+data.title+'</p>'
          +'<p class="desc">'+data.propInfo+'</p>'
          +'<a href="http://'+data.link+'" target="_blank" class="view">View Community</a>'
        +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
    +'</div>');
    $('a.expand, .thumb', div).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var pixPosition = me.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(me.latlng_);
      div.toggleClass('open');
      if(div.hasClass('open')) {
        div.css('top', (pixPosition.y + -158) + "px");
        div.css('z-index', 20);
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('.info_window_data', div).show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 300);
        }, 100);
      } else {
        div.css('top', (pixPosition.y + -85) + "px");
        div.css('z-index', 10);
        $('.info_window_data', div).hide();
      }
    });

    div.css('display', 'none');
    $(panes.floatPane).append(div);
  }
}

InfoBox.prototype.createCityElement = function() {
  var me = this;
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  var div = this.div_;
  var data = this.data_;
  if (!div) {
    div = this.div_ = $('<div class="map_city_window">'
      +'<a href="/find/where?query='+data.name+'">'+data.name+'</a>'
      +'<div class="arrow">arrow</div>'
    +'</div>');
    div.css('display', 'none');
    $(panes.floatPane).append(div);
  }
};
```

I am not sure how to integrate that function in this code, but if someone could give me some pointers, I would greatly appreciate that. A very similar example of the map I am using is this if it would help as a reference point:

http://gables.com/find/where?query=Washington%20DC

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The standard design pattern for this is:

1. Place a single reference to a window at a higher location in the scope (rather than at each marker as you have now) and treat the window as a Singleton.
2. When a marker click event in received, close the window and empty its contents.
3. Place whatever new content is appropriate in the window and move it to the location that is appropriate for the current marker click.
4. Display the window, then wait to repeat these steps if another marker click event is received.

Check this question for more detail about using this pattern with an `InfoWindow`: [Have just one InfoWindow open in Google Maps API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1875596/1314132).