# Check if infowindow is opened Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

Please, I need a help.

I want to check if my infowindow is opened.

For example:

```
if (infowindow.isOpened)
{
   doSomething()
}
```

or

```
if (infowindow.close)
{
   doAnotherthing();
}
```

I dont have any idea, how to do this

Comment: Why not just check the infoWindow's content has a parentElement?  InfoWindow has a documented 'content' property, so you just need to check if it has a parentElement, or not: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindowOptions.content
Perhaps it depends on how you set the content (string or node).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is an undocumented feature, and is therefore subject to change without notice, however the `infoWindow.close()` method sets the map on the object to `null` (this is why `infoWindow.open(map, [anchor])` requires that you pass in a `Map`), so you can check this property to tell if it is currently being displayed:

```
function isInfoWindowOpen(infoWindow){
    var map = infoWindow.getMap();
    return (map !== null && typeof map !== "undefined");
}

if (isInfoWindowOpen(infoWindow)){
    // do something if it is open
} else {
    // do something if it is closed
}
```

**Update:**
Another potentially useful way to write this is to add an `isOpen()` method to the `InfoWindow` `prototype`.

```
google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.isOpen = function(){
    var map = this.getMap();
    return (map !== null && typeof map !== "undefined");
}
```

Comment: The infoWindow class does not have a method called .getMap().

Comment: In the documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) it is not listed, but it works for me. You can see a screenshot of it listed in the Chrome console here: http://imgur.com/0byQx

Comment: This Google Groups post has the same suggestion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-maps-js-api-v3/_L0RdmgNCbo/IB2MlW5iwpgJ

Comment: The thing about undocumented features is that they may change, or vanish altogether, without warning in a future update. I would advise against using them, even if they seem to work here and now.

Comment: Completely agree, however the alternate answer to the above question is "you can't" so I figured it was better than nothing. I will edit to to indicate that it is an undocumented feature.

Comment: I tried to use the call the function Initialize(); and put to call on the final of initialize isInfoWindowOpen(infoWindow);, then, I had put the if(isInfoWindowOpen)...etc, but it dont worked, I tested with alerts, when I call the function nothing work...=/

Comment: Can you post the full code? I tested with some of my own implementations and it **does** work, it just isn't officially supported as @Marcelo noted. You don't need to have the function defined as I did, assuming the variable is called `infoWindow` you can also write it as: `if (infoWindow.getMap()) { window.alert('visible'); } else { window.alert('hidden'); }`

Comment: The function in the post is the wrong way round - returns false when infowindow is open.

Comment: Thanks for that, i don't know why you ask for `"undefined"`; but i use `getMap() != null` to know if it's opened or closed. Here's my my [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24657050/2835520)

Comment: This is good if you only have to deal with one marker. If you have multiple markers that each update the InfoWindow object on click and you want to implement a toggle (click on marker to open, click on it again to close), then this won't work.

Answer (score 26):

Until google doesn't give us any better way of doing this, you can add a property to the infoWindow objects. Something like:

```
google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.opened = false;
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: '<h1> Olá mundo </h1>'});

if(infoWindow.opened){
   // do something
   infoWindow.opened = false;
}
else{
   // do something else
   infoWindow.opened = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's better than use undocumented google's function

Comment: I definitely prefer this approach. You'll likely have some form of "marker manager" anyway, so implementing this is easy.

Comment: Clear and fast solution, working and after almost 7 years. Thanks

Comment: One small issue, the user can close the info window by clicking "x", hence the "opened" state will be out of sync.

Comment: Adding to my comment, you can fix the mentioned issue by using the "closeclick" event https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindow.closeclick

Answer (score 12):

I modified the prototype for google.maps.InfoWindow and changed open/close to set/clear a property:

```
//
// modify the prototype for google.maps.Infowindow so that it is capable of tracking
// the opened state of the window.  we track the state via boolean which is set when
// open() or close() are called.  in addition to these, the closeclick event is
// monitored so that the value of _openedState can be set when the close button is
// clicked (see code at bottom of this file).
//
google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype._open = google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.open;
google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype._close = google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.close;
google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype._openedState = false;

google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.open =
    function (map, anchor) {
        this._openedState = true;
        this._open(map, anchor);
    };

google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.close =
    function () {
        this._openedState = false;
        this._close();
    };

google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.getOpenedState =
    function () {
        return this._openedState;
    };

google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.setOpenedState =
    function (val) {
        this._openedState = val;
    };
```

You also need to monitor the closeclick event because clicking on the close button does not call close().

```
//
// monitor the closelick event and set opened state false when the close
// button is clicked.
//
(function (w) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(w, "closeclick", function (e) {
        w.setOpenedState(false);
    });
})(infowindow);
```

Calling `InfoWindow.getOpenedState()` returns a boolean which reflects the state (opened/closed) of the infowindow.

I chose to do it this way instead of the using the `InfoWindow.getMap()` or `MVCObject.get('map')` method because of the well known pitfalls of using undocumented behavior.  However google uses `MVCObject.set('map', null)` to force the removal of the InfoWindow from the DOM, so it is unlikely that this will change...

Answer (score 3):

`infowindow.getMap()` returns null if `infowindow` is closed.

So you can use simply:

```
if (infowindow.getMap());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set `key` and `value` for infoWindow: `infoWindow.set('closed', true);`

**example:**

```js
const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'foo',
    position: {
        lat: some_number,
        lng: some_number
    }
});

infoWindow.set('closed', true);

// Clicking on polyline for this example
// Can be marker too
polyline.addListener(
    'click',
    () => {
        if (infoWindow.get('closed')) {
            infoWindow.open(map);
            infoWindow.set('closed', false);
        } else {
            infoWindow.close();
            infoWindow.set('closed', true);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: best and easiest solution of all to this day, no need to hack or modify/add functionality, just using the one that is provided. Wondering if the set method was available when OP asked the question! Dakujem velmi pekne

Comment: I just stumbled across the similar need, and saw this answer. Love it. Very straightforward and lightweight! Saved me the need to bloat my code with an extra function.