# Suggestion box only displays , ,

Tags: javascript, mashup

I am making a mashup website that involves a map, and a search textbox in javascript. So as the title says, no matter what is inputted into the search box, only 2 commas appear in the suggestion box and when the suggestion is clicked on, it turn the map gray and unusable. Whats the problem? This is my javascript file, the function where this is located is in the configure function

```
// Google Map
var map;

// markers for map
var markers = [];

// info window
var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

// execute when the DOM is fully loaded
$(function() {

// styles for map
// https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling
var styles = [

    // hide Google's labels
    {
        featureType: "all",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [
            {visibility: "off"}
        ]
    },

    // hide roads
    {
        featureType: "road",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [
            {visibility: "off"}
        ]
    }

];

// options for map
// https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
var options = {
    center: {lat: 35.7640, lng: -78.7786}, // Cary, North Carolina
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    maxZoom: 14,
    panControl: true,
    styles: styles,
    zoom: 13,
    zoomControl: true
};

// get DOM node in which map will be instantiated
var canvas = $("#map-canvas").get(0);

// instantiate map
map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, options);

// configure UI once Google Map is idle (i.e., loaded)
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", configure);

});

/**
 * Adds marker for place to map.
 */
function addMarker(place)
{
var url = "/search?q=" + place;
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    var location = data.latitude + data.longitude;
    mark = new google.maps.marker(location, map);
    markers[0] = mark;
});

}

/**
 * Configures application.
 */
function configure()
{
// update UI after map has been dragged
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dragend", function() {

    // if info window isn't open
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/12410385
    if (!info.getMap || !info.getMap())
    {
        update();
    }
});

// update UI after zoom level changes
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "zoom_changed", function() {
    update();
});

// configure typeahead
$("#q").typeahead({
    highlight: false,
    minLength: 1
},
{
    display: function(suggestion) { return null; },
    limit: 10,
    source: search,
    templates: {
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile(
            "<div>" +
            "<p>{{ place_name }}, {{ admin_name1 }}, {{ postal_code }}</p>" +
            "</div>"
        )
    }
});

// re-center map after place is selected from drop-down
$("#q").on("typeahead:selected", function(eventObject, suggestion, name) {

    // set map's center
    map.setCenter({lat: parseFloat(suggestion.latitude), lng: parseFloat(suggestion.longitude)});

    // update UI
    update();
});

// hide info window when text box has focus
$("#q").focus(function(eventData) {
    info.close();
});

// re-enable ctrl- and right-clicking (and thus Inspect Element) on Google Map
// https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-right-click/hompjdfbfmmmgflfjdlnkohcplmboaeo?hl=en
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(event) {
    event.returnValue = true; 
    event.stopPropagation && event.stopPropagation(); 
    event.cancelBubble && event.cancelBubble();
}, true);

// update UI
update();

// give focus to text box
$("#q").focus();
}

/**
 * Removes markers from map.
 */
function removeMarkers()
{
// TODO
}

/**
 * Searches database for typeahead's suggestions.
 */
function search(query, syncResults, asyncResults)
{
// get places matching query (asynchronously)
var parameters = {
    q: query
};
$.getJSON(Flask.url_for("search"), parameters)
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    // call typeahead's callback with search results (i.e., places)
    asyncResults(data);
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    // log error to browser's console
    console.log(errorThrown.toString());

    // call typeahead's callback with no results
    asyncResults([]);
});
}

/**
 * Shows info window at marker with content.
 */
function showInfo(marker, content)
{
// start div
var div = "<div id='info'>";
if (typeof(content) == "undefined")
{
    // http://www.ajaxload.info/
    div += "<img alt='loading' src='/static/ajax-loader.gif'/>";
}
else
{
    div += content;
}

// end div
div += "</div>";

// set info window's content
info.setContent(div);

// open info window (if not already open)
info.open(map, marker);
}

/**
 * Updates UI's markers.
 */
function update() 
{
// get map's bounds
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();

// get places within bounds (asynchronously)
var parameters = {
    ne: ne.lat() + "," + ne.lng(),
    q: $("#q").val(),
    sw: sw.lat() + "," + sw.lng()
};
$.getJSON(Flask.url_for("update"), parameters)
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

   // remove old markers from map
   removeMarkers();

   // add new markers to map
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
   {
       addMarker(data[i]);
   }
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    // log error to browser's console
    console.log(errorThrown.toString());
});
};
```

Comment: Edit your question and paste your code directly into the question.  Don't use pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, figured out that in my application.py, I should have put jsonify(value) instead of jsonify([value]).